# Returning the second largest in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def second_largest(nums):
    the, sec = 0, 0
    if nums[0] > nums[1]:
        the, sec = nums[0], nums[1]
    else:
        the, sec = nums[1], nums[0]

    for num in nums:
        if num > sec:
            if num >= the:
                the, sec = num, the
            else:
                sec = num
    return sec
```

This is my code to get second largest element from the list.
I assumed that a list has at least two elements. 
However, it gives me 'gamma' not 'delta' from the input below.

```
print(second_largest(['alpha', 'gamma','beta','delta']))
```

Comment: Well, write your algorithm on paper. What do you get?

Comment: Why not just `sorted(['alpha', 'gamma','beta','delta'], reverse=True)[1]` ?

Comment: @zwer: That has worse time and space complexity.

Comment: @Ryan - premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @zwer: Who says it's premature? There's a better-than-even chance that this is a homework assignment with getting O(n) as a goal, anyway.

Comment: @zwer It is a practice. So I try not to use built-in now.

Comment: @cricket_007 Understood. But your comments still don't help me now. The second largest must be delta, but it gives me gamma. Alphabetically, 'delta' is the second largest.

Comment: If we're optimizing with builtins, see `heapq.nlargest`

Comment: Derp... I was thinking second element in ascending, not descending

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've initialized the largest and second-largest values to the first two items in the appropriate order, but then you're including them again in the loop. If the largest value was also one of the first two values, it will take up both slots after that point. You can fix it by creating an iterator from the list explicitly and advancing it for the first two elements:

```
def second_largest(nums):
    it = iter(nums)
    sec, the = sorted((next(it), next(it)))

    for num in it:
        if num > sec:
            if num >= the:
                the, sec = num, the
            else:
                sec = num

    return sec
```

By not using indexed access, this also has the advantage of working on any iterable.

For real-world use, see [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), which even has specific optimizations in CPython for small numbers of elements.

Comment: Does this work as intended? `second_largest(['alpha', 'gamma','beta','delta', 'echo'])`
 returns `echo`

Comment: @cricket_007: Yeah, because "g" comes after "e".

Comment: Hmm. It's getting late, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is to find max and remove it. finding the max is on o(n)

```
>>> x=['alpha', 'gamma','beta','delta']
>>> m=x[0]
>>> for i in x:
    if i > m:
        m=i

>>> x.remove(m)
```

and for second time:

```
>>> m=x[0]
>>> for i in x:
    if i > m:
        m=i
>>> print(m) #scond max
```

o(n)+...+o(n) ->  L * o(n) -> o(n)